# Laravel 4 Installation Problems on WAMP/Windows

Tags: windows, laravel, wamp, laravel-4

First,I use wamp on my Window7.I open php-openssl,and I git pull the laravel from github.com,and then I put laravel on my d:/wamp/www/, I change the c:/windows/system32.But when I open the url

```
http://localhost/laravel/public
```

I see this question.
[image: the pic]

I am a newbie on laravel,and without install on Ubuntu.Where is my wrong, without no pear,or something else? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need to run `composer install` in a command prompt.

If you do not have composer, download the `phar` file from their website.

Place the file you just downloaded into the `laravel` directory.

Then, make sure that the absolute path to `php.exe` is added to your `PATH` environment variable.

Then, you can hold down shift, and right click anywhere inside the `laravel` directory, and open up a command prompt window. Then, run `php composer.phar install`. The process may take some time, depending on the speed of your internet connection.

Instead of using the above method, you can download the Composer installer for Windows, install it, and just run `composer install`.

Note that you only need to do this in order to put the Laravel components together. You do not need to run it on a live server.

Please consult the Laravel Docs for installation and other instructions: http://laravel.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

### **Try This :**

**Installing Laravel 4 on WAMP**

**1. Enable OpenSSL**

OpenSSL must be enabled in the PHP configuration.

Edit php.ini in your WAMP’s PHP folder, e.g.:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\
```

Note: This is not the php.ini in C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin.

Find the following line and remove the semicolon save it:

`;extension=php_openssl.dll` changed to `extension=php_openssl.dll`

**2. Install Composer**

(i).Download the Composer Windows installer from getcomposer.org.

(ii). Run the installer.

(iii). When it asks for the location of php.exe, point it to the executable in your WAMP’s PHP folder, e.g.:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\
```

(iv). Finish the installation.

(v). Open a command-line interface (cmd) and type:

```
composer
```

It should return a list of options. If you get an error, restart your computer and try again.

Composer has now been installed and added to your PATH environment variable. This means you can run it from any directory using the command-line interface.

Now we need to install Composer. This is a dependency manager that will download the latest release of Laravel and specific versions of Laravel’s dependencies, such as Doctrine and Symfony.

**3.Install Laravel**

Now that Composer has been installed, Composer can download and install Laravel onto your system.

(i). Open a command-line interface (cmd).

(ii). Go to the directory in which you want to install Laravel. This is usually your development directory. In this tutorial, we’ll use `C:\wamp\www\laravel`

(iii). Instruct Composer to install Laravel into a project directory. we use project name myproject.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject --prefer-dist
```

**Note:** `This will install Laravel in a subdirectory myproject of the current working directory.`

Three type of installation to be completed
Now your project was running directory like

```
C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject\public\
```

After completed put tick mark and increase the point....

Answer (score 0):

Do `php composer.phar dump-autoload` or `php artisan dump-autoload`

Comment: Is there I don't down all the resource from the web?

Comment: dump-autload Recompile all the classes specified in composer.json